# Initialization On Demand Holder idiom

Tags: java, c++, static, singleton, lazy-initialization

This is the implementation mostly seen on the web

```
private static class LazySomethingHolder {
  public static Something something = new Something();
}

public static Something getInstance() {
  return LazySomethingHolder.something;
}
```

Is the following simpler variation correct, if not what is wrong with it? Is the problem specific to java or also present in C++?

```
public static Something getInstance() {
  private static Something something = new Something();
  return something;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have static local variables in Java.

Simpler alternatives are

```
private static final Something something = new Something();

public static Something getInstance() {
  return something;
}
```

or my preference if for.

```
enum Something {
    INSTANCE;
}
```

The only problem with these patterns is that if you have multiple instances you want lazily loaded, you need to have a class each, or loading one will mean loading them all.

Comment: "You can have static fields inside a method in Java." there is a typo here

Comment: Since Java 16 (I think), you can have static fields in a method by encapsulating them in a local class.

Answer (score 1):

Java (unlike c++) doesn't have local static variables, so what you describe is simply not possible. In c++ you would most likely write (known as meyer singleton):

```
public static Something& getInstance() {
    static Something something{};
    return something;
}
```

Comment: `something{}` what does this do? I have seen it first time.

Comment: @q126y: It default initializes `something`. If something is a class you can also omit it.

Comment: @q126y: It is part of c++ since c++11 and called uniform initialization syntax.